# Labels duplicating?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm trying to add a timer on the side of the thumbnail but the UIlabel for the timer is always duplicating when I scroll.

It ends up like this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: http://gyazo.com/0d22d9e3adc0ecbbacd8cb2cdb59d8b4.png]

This is how my method looks like

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    ChanelFeeds *currentFeed = [[xmlParser feeds] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

        CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 120, 90);
        self.customImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageFrame];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:self.customImage];
        [self.customImage release];

        // Title
        CGRect contentFrame = CGRectMake(122, 2, 198, 45);
        UILabel *title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame];
        title.tag = 0011;
        title.numberOfLines = 2;
        title.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        title.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        title.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:title];
        [title release];

        // Views Placement
        CGRect contentFrame2 = CGRectMake(127, 70, 180, 15);
        UILabel *title2 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame2];
        title2.tag = 0012;
        title2.numberOfLines = 1;
        title2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        title2.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        title2.font = [UIFont italicSystemFontOfSize:14];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:title2];
        [title2 release];



        //Here's where the fails come in


        CGRect contentFrame6 = CGRectMake(0, 66, 33, 13);
        CGRect contentFrame7 = CGRectMake(6, 65, 60, 15);
        UIImageView *imv5 = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:contentFrame6];
        UILabel *title3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame7];
        imv5.alpha = 1;
        title3.tag = 0013;
        imv5.tag = 0014;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imv5];
        imv5.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];


    }

    // Formatting views
    NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init]; [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];  NSNumber * formattedViews = [f numberFromString
    :[currentFeed views]]; [f release]; NSNumber *firstNumber = formattedViews; NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];[formatter setNumberStyle: NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; convertedNumber = [formatter stringForObjectValue:firstNumber];


    // Basic stuff
    UILabel *title = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:0011];
    UILabel *title2 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:0012];
    UILabel *title3 = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:0013];

    title.text = [currentFeed title];
    title2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ views", convertedNumber];


    totalTime = [self timeFormatted:([currentFeed duration].intValue)-1];
    NSString *word = @":00:";
    if ([totalTime rangeOfString:word].location == NSNotFound) {
        totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"00:" withString:@""];
        totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"01:" withString:@"1:"];
        totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"02:" withString:@"2:"];
        totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"03:" withString:@"3:"];
        totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"04:" withString:@"4:"];
        totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"05:" withString:@"5:"];
        totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"06:" withString:@"6:"];
        totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"07:" withString:@"7:"];
        totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"08:" withString:@"8:"];
        totalTime = [totalTime stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"09:" withString:@"9:"];}
    if([totalTime length] >= 5) {
        CGRect contentFrame7 = CGRectMake(4, 65, 60, 15);
        title3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame7];
        title3.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        title3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        title3.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10];
    } else {
        CGRect contentFrame7 = CGRectMake(6, 65, 60, 15);
        title3 = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:contentFrame7];
        title3.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        title3.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        title3.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10];

    }
    title3.text = totalTime;
   [cell.contentView addSubview:title3];



    NSString *directoryPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSURL *imgURL = [currentFeed thumbnailURL];
    NSArray *parts = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", imgURL] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];
    NSString *imageName = [parts objectAtIndex:[parts count]-2];

    NSString *filePath = [directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:imageName];

    UIImage  *myview = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
    if(myview){
        cell.imageView.image = myview;

        //Add Black fucking border and stuff here!!!
    }else{


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
            NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[currentFeed thumbnailURL]];
            UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
            cell.imageView.image = thumbnail;
            [self.feedsTableView beginUpdates];
            [self.feedsTableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil]
                                       withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
            [self.feedsTableView endUpdates];


        });
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Manually formatting @"00", @"01", etc, and updating the UI from a background thread. Have you no shame?

Comment: @Abizern He's obviously a beginner. Manual formatting is terrible from code quality perspective but it's not really incorrect. However, the background thread, especially triggered from this method, is a very wrong thing to do.

Comment: What else could I do for example ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obvious:

Don't add any views outside the `(cell == nil)` block.

Cells are reused, that means that if you add any label to a reused cell, there will be two labels... and more if the cell is reused again.

There are many other problematic parts. For example, starting cell reloading from inside this method is VERY strange.

Also, the code would be simplified a lot, if you used a xib for the cell design.

Comment: Thanks I added everything inside the (cell == nil) block and it seems to be working.

Comment: Crap, I'm not sure what's wrong but it seems like the first 7 cells just duplicate over and over again.

Comment: @IamGretar That's called "reusing". When scrolling, no new cells are created. The old ones are reused.

Comment: Why would I then put them in (cell == nil) If I need to reuse them again and again and again while scrolling ?

Comment: @IamGretar You want to put the view creation into `if (cell == nil)` branch (that means adding subviews, setting fonts, etc). Everything else (that is - setting content from data, label texts etc) outside the block. It's very simple.